How do I fetch `to` and `from` addresses from a fetched transaction on `solana/web3js`?
I am trying to fetch transaction details and list down the necessary details. I tried to fetch the to and from addresses by checking the instruction.type, to see if it is transfer or transferChecked.
    let signatures = await getSigsInRange(address, endSlot, startSlot);
    let signatureMapping = signatures.map((transaction) => transaction.signature);
    let transactionDetails = await solanaConnection.getParsedTransactions(signatureMapping, {maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0, commitment: 'confirmed'});

    signatures.forEach((transaction, i) => {
        const message = transactionDetails[i].transaction.message;
        const transactionInstructions = message.instructions;

        transactionInstructions.forEach((instruction, n)=> {

            // testing to and from source of tx
            const parsedInstruction = instruction.parsed;
            if (instruction && instruction.type === 'transfer') {
                const fromAddress = instruction.info.source;
                const toAddress = instruction.info.destination;
                const amount = instruction.info.amount;

                console.log(`Token Transfer: ${amount} tokens from ${fromAddress} to ${toAddress}`);
            } else if (instruction && instruction.type === 'transferChecked') {
                const fromAddress = instruction.info.source;
                const toAddress = instruction.info.destination;
                const amount = instruction.info.tokenAmount.uiAmount;

                console.log(`Token TransferChecked: ${amount} tokens from ${fromAddress} to ${toAddress}`);
            }
        });

The above is a code snippet with the relevant information, I have been able to fetch transactions successfully and print all the other information properly too but I don't understand how else I can figure out the addresses of the users participating in the transaction. How do I figure out who is sending tokens to whom? Thanks for helping!

You have the source and destination address in your code already. What else are you looking for?

It is not returning the addresses, I get a blank output every time. I am looking for an alternate way to get the source and destination addresses as this is not working.

Should you be looking at parsedInstruction instead of instruction?

I made some changes to your code to ensure more accurate and comprehensive extraction of transaction details. These changes include checking additional instruction types like transferCheckedWithSeed, consistently using parsed data for accuracy, processing all instructions in a transaction to capture every transfer, and considering the need to resolve Associated Token Accounts (ATAs) to their actual wallet addresses. These adjustments might help ensure you don’t miss any relevant information, making the code more reliable in identifying who is sending tokens to whom in thetransactions.
signatures.forEach((transaction, i) => {
    const message = transactionDetails[i].transaction.message;
    const transactionInstructions = message.instructions;

    transactionInstructions.forEach((instruction, n) => {
        const parsedInstruction = instruction.parsed;

        if (parsedInstruction && parsedInstruction.type === 'transfer') {
            const fromAddress = parsedInstruction.info.source;
            const toAddress = parsedInstruction.info.destination;
            const amount = parsedInstruction.info.amount;

            console.log(`Token Transfer: ${amount} tokens from ${fromAddress} to ${toAddress}`);
        } else if (parsedInstruction && parsedInstruction.type === 'transferChecked') {
            const fromAddress = parsedInstruction.info.source;
            const toAddress = parsedInstruction.info.destination;
            const amount = parsedInstruction.info.tokenAmount.uiAmount;

            console.log(`Token TransferChecked: ${amount} tokens from ${fromAddress} to ${toAddress}`);
        } else if (parsedInstruction && parsedInstruction.type === 'transferCheckedWithSeed') {
            const fromAddress = parsedInstruction.info.source;
            const toAddress = parsedInstruction.info.destination;
            const amount = parsedInstruction.info.tokenAmount.uiAmount;

            console.log(`Token TransferCheckedWithSeed: ${amount} tokens from ${fromAddress} to ${toAddress}`);
        }
    });
});

